# Shell Script (Linux): Copy and overwrite only files that have changed in destination?

Tags: sh

I want to do the following in Shell Script:

I have two directories and I want to copy over only these files from the source directory that have changed or are missing in the destination directory.

**Note 0:** (in case the above is clear): I want to replace destination folder with source directory. Changed files in destination should be restored to the original state from the source directory. Unchanged files should not be touched (to save time).

**Note 1:** I looked up rsynch but I cannot figure out if it can do what I want. There is only -u but that doesn't seem to do what I want.

**EDIT:** This is my script: (fixed)

```
#!/bin/sh

################################################################################
# Copies resources to build output directory (Ubuntu)
################################################################################

directoryWtSource="/usr/share/Wt"
directoryBuildOutput="bin__output__"

# Get the absolute path to the script
scriptPath=`readlink -e $0`
directoryDestination=`dirname $scriptPath`

################################################################################
# Start
################################################################################

cd ..
directoryWtSourceResources=$directoryWtSource/resources
directoryBuildOutputResources=${PWD}/$directoryBuildOutput

if [ ! -d ${PWD}/$directoryBuildOutput ]
then
    mkdir ${PWD}/$directoryBuildOutput
fi


#echo $directoryWtSourceResources
#echo $directoryBuildOutputResources

# BEGIN - REMOVE THIS: No need for cp
#if [ ! -d $directoryBuildOutputResources ]
#then
#    echo "  --> No destination directory found: copying resources..."
#    cp -Rp $directoryWtSourceResources $directoryBuildOutputResources
#else
#    echo "  --> Destination directory found: won't copy."
#fi
# END - REMOVE THIS

rsync -arv $directoryWtSourceResources $directoryBuildOutputResources

################################################################################
# End
################################################################################
```

Comment: I looked at it but I can't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync` can do this:

```
rsync -av source/ destination/
```

This command will also print out the list of files that have been replaced.

Comment: rsync -arv - This won't replace a file that was changed in destination. I just tried that.

Comment: @Zingam No need for `-r`: `-a` includes it. Could you give a detailed file list (`ls -ls`) of your source and destination? Edit the question to include it.

Comment: I added my script. Warning: It might not be the best script ever.

Comment: OK. I might have a bug here. I need to investigate.